# Automatic failover not happening in repmgr

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, database-replication, database-cluster, repmgr

I have a postgres active/standby cluster of 2 nodes, I have used repmgr for creating the cluster. The issue is, automatic failover is not happening when I stop the postgres services on master node. Contents of file repmgr.conf on master are as follows:

```
node_id=1
data_directory='/data/pgdatabase/masterdb/data'
node_name=node1
conninfo='host=IP-Of-Master user=repmgr dbname=repmgr'
failover=automatic
promote_command='repmgr standby promote -f /etc/repmgr/11/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
follow_command='repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr/11/repmgr.conf --log-to-file  --upstream-node-id=%n'
log_file='/var/log/repmgr/repmgr.log'
log_level=NOTICE
reconnect_attempts=4
reconnect_interval=5
repmgrd_service_start_command='sudo systemctl repmgr11 start'
repmgrd_service_stop_command='sudo systemctl repmgr11 stop'
```

Contents of postgresql.conf are as follows:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr'
max_wal_senders = 15
max_replication_slots = 15
wal_level = 'replica'
hot_standby = on
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/pgsql/11/archive/%f'
```

The contents are same on master and slave expect the name, which is node2 on slave. 
Can anyone guide me what can be possible reason for automatic failover not happening

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it myself, I needed to create file /etc/default/repmgrd and add following lines into it

```
REPMGRD_ENABLED=yes
REPMGRD_CONF="/etc/repmgr.conf"
```

Comment: There is yet some issue. When node 1 is primary and node 2 is slave, on switchover, node 2 becomes primary. But when node 2 is primary but node 1 is slave, node 1 does not promote to primary